# How do I interpret log exponential non-linear regression?

Tags: sas, exponential, ln, interpretation

I am using an exponential non-linear regression in order to fit my data.

Here is my model:

```
O-acetyl content = A*exp(-B*Time)+C
with:
-   A: amplitude of decrease (difference between the intercept T0 and the plateau);
-   B: speed of decrease (curvature);
-   C: low plateau;
-   O-acetyl content: expressed in µmol/dose;
-   Time: expressed in hours.
```

I have to pass my dependant variable (O-acetyl content) into ln . I have obtained my coefficients but how do I interpret the results? I am using and the Newthon method of coeff estimation.

I have for instance these results for the parameter estimates:

```
A = 0.062 
B=0.0573 
C=0.0309
```

my SAS script (a part):

```
proc nlin data=donn method=newton; 
    parms A=0.8815 B=0.0124 C=4.4067;
    if (CCR="before_change") then do;
        beta_1 = A1;
        beta_2 = B1;
        beta_0 = C1;
    end;
    else do;
        beta_1 = A2; 
        beta_2 = B2; 
        beta_0 = C2;
    end;

    model l_AgHA=beta_0 + beta_1*exp(-beta_2*hours); *variable dependante en ln;
    output out=nlinexp_full predicted=pred l95m=l95mean u95m=u95mean 
                                      l95=l95ind u95=u95ind;
    ods output ParameterEstimates=pest_full; 
    ods output Anova=aovred_full(rename=(ss=ssred ms=msred df=dfred));
run;
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: This may be best asked in cross-validated.

Comment: Is it about interpreting the SAS results or interpreting the results in general? If it is the latter I agree with @StuSztukowski. If not, what exactly do you need to interpret?